# "as though" vs. "to pretend"

Tags: meaning

This is something that confuses me from time to time:

> They didn't have any real money so they acted as though they had.
>
> They didn't have any real money so they pretended like they had.

Do these two sentences mean the same thing?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense and the phrases are not interchangeable because of their very different and effective meanings. You did not present any research behind your question.

Comment: ok sorry I edited.

Comment: sorry it still doesn't make sense and doesn't provide any research

Comment: @AJdollasign21 I edited sorry.

Comment: you are already using although in the first sentence. 2nd:there is no research based on your answer

Comment: @AJdollasign21 research? what about google translate? :)

Comment: huh? what are you saying google translate? You're supposed to research your  question and provide research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following terms are synonymous; thus, you may interchange them as you did above.

- *as though*
- *pretend*

However, your above two statements are grammatically incorrect. In both instances you used the word **didn't**, which establishes a past-tense; thus, the verbs that follow must also be:

> They didn't have any real money so they act**ed** as though they had.
>
> They didn't have any real money so they pretend**ed** like they had.

Comment: thank you so what about, "they didn't have any real money so they had to pretend" and "they didn't have any real money so they had to act as though they had" ?

Comment: Sure, those two are grammatically correct, but I'm thinking that using the word "did" in place of "had" in your second sentence would be easier to understand.